# Navigation Bar is pushed up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am having an issue where I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs and they each have their own navigation controller with table view controllers as root views and when the app first loads the navigation bar of the first tab is pushed up behind the status bar.

I am pretty sure this problem has something to do with constraints but I can't seem to figure out what constraints I need to change.

Code Example

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

....


let firstNavVC = FirstNavViewController()
let secondNavVC = SecondNavViewController()
let thirdNavVC = ThirdNavViewController()
let fourthNavVC = FourthNavViewController()



self.viewControllers = [firstNavVC, secondNavVC, thirdNavVC, fourthNavVC]

...
}

class FirstNavViwController: UINavigationController {

...

let vc = TableViewController()

self.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)


...
}
```

[Result when app loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WwVr.png)

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9eif.png)

Comment: In Result when app loads.
That's first screen where navigationController Embedded.
And in How it should look is push from Embedded screen in which you hide its bck button simply.

Comment: I updated the "Result when app load" picture. The problem is still there with navigation item in the navigation bar. The the "How it should look" picture is when you change the tab on the tab bar. Not adding to the navigation stack and going back

Comment: please update your storyboard screenshot

Comment: And also check your rootviewController if you assigned any.

Comment: Probably not related to constraints. Is the `isNavigationBarHidden` property ever set to `true` in code or storyboard?

Comment: IsNavigationBarHidden is never set to true and I am also not using a storyboard.

Comment: Sometimes it's related to constraints as well due to top safeArea & no default it's never.

Comment: Well then need to review your code in that case.

Comment: did you tried this one self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false ??

Answer (score 0):

Please add `self.isNavigationBarHidden = false` in your FirstNavViwController and check, it should work

Comment: That didn’t work. The second picture I have linked is when you click on another tab and go back. If that helps

Comment: If you have added above line in viewDidLoad method then can you please add in viewWillAppear and try again

Comment: Well then I recommend you to follow this , may be it helpful for you https://medium.com/@satindersingh71/uitabbarcontroller-programmatically-2a3df63607f1

Answer (score 0):

Remove top constraint and add top constraint to safe area layout guide.

Comment: for the tableview?

Comment: yes. and also check if safe area layout guide is enabled on that storyboard. if error is due to safe area than it will work fine on iphone 8 and prior devices and problem will be only with x and above device

Comment: it happens without the tableview. and I'm not using a storyboard

Comment: try to run code on iphone 8/7 and let me know about the result

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false` this line of code in the First `ViewController` of each `NavigationController` from tabs.